# How can I install Nvclock on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, overclocking

I'm trying to regulate my GPU fan's speed without the GUI in Nvidia X server settings.
When I try to install with apt-get: `sudo apt-get nvclock`, apt-get is unable to locate the package. 
I believe that for Ubuntu 14.04 it is available. How can I get it on 16.04?

Comment: [TTVUKT](https://askubuntu.com/questions/859218/nvidia-1070-overclocking-help-needed) explains how he got Nvidia overclocking working and getting good performance levels on 16.04 without installing nvclock.

Comment: Though it isn't strictly speaking an answer to the question I originally asked, the solution in the answer you linked to is more convenient, as I already have nvidia-setting installed! The command that I used was `nvidia-settings -a '[fan:0]/GPUTargetFanSpeed=30'`

Comment: Thanks @karel, the thing is, it doesn't answer the question in the title, but proposes an alternative. It works, and I'm very grateful, but if I marked it as an answer, it could be misleading.

Comment: I'm leaving my answer here anyway following the suggestion in this post at Meta Stack Exchange: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) (asking about your attempted solution rather than your *actual problem*) but you're right, that is also what comments are for.

Answer (score 2):

[TTVUKT](https://askubuntu.com/questions/859218/nvidia-1070-overclocking-help-needed) explains how he got Nvidia overclocking working and getting good performance levels on 16.04 without installing nvclock.

> Needed to install Nvidia driver 375.20.
>
> Install Ubuntu 16.04 with enabling software update options for Ubuntu
>   Development team and third parties.
>
> On reboot, after installation open up Ubuntu Software - update the
>   OS and reboot.
>
> So, first install the default Nvidia driver through *Software &
>   Updates*, and then *Additional Drivers*. The Ubuntu Nvidia 367.57 driver
>   includes extra tweaks from the Ubuntu development team for maximum GPU performance.
>
> Reboot.
>
> Now switch back to the non-Nvidia drivers in *Software & Updates*.
>
> Reboot.
>
> Now, you can install the latest Nvidia drivers and get the maximum GPU performance.
>
> Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to get into
>   a text-only virtual console.
>
> Log in.
>
> Switch off x-server with:
>
> ```
> sudo service lightdm stop.
> ```
>
> Got to Downloads folder with:
>
> ```
> cd ~/Downloads
> ls
> ```
>
> This will display driver name and run with:
>
> ```
> sudo sh ./AND NVIDIA NAME LISTED
> ```
>
> There will be two error messages, but ignore them and say yes at the
>   prompts.
>
> Then, switch the x-server back on with:
>
> ```
> sudo service lightdm start
> ```
>
> Reboot PC.
>
> Then run this in terminal:
>
> ```
> sudo update-grub
> sudo nvidia-xconfig -a --cool-bits=28 --allow-empty-initial-configuration
> ```
>
> Finally, you can enter overclocking settings and fan controls by
>   creating startup .sh file by copying and pasting this into empty
>   document amending for desired fans speed and clock settings.
>
> To finish, you will create a startup .sh file for each GPU so the
>   overclock settings and fan speed are loaded when you login to Ubuntu 16.04.
>
> Create some empty documents on Ubuntu Desktop and call them whatever
>   you like. Make sure the filename has .sh at the end.
>
> Paste in:
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash
>
> nvidia-settings -a '[gpu:0]/GPUGraphicsMemoryOffset[3]=100'
> nvidia-settings -a '[gpu:0]/GPUMemoryTransferRateOffset[3]=100'
> nvidia-settings -a '[gpu:0]/GPUFanControlState=1'
> nvidia-settings -a '[fan:0]/GPUTargetFanSpeed=30'
> ```
>
> Amend the clocks (GPU and Memory) and fan speeds to whatever are you
>   comfortable with. Make separate documents for each GPU by changing the
>   numbers for each card.
>
> Save and open properties and make each file "executable".
>
> Then open the Dash and find Startup Applications, and add these files
>   to the programs you run when you start up the Ubuntu 16.04 desktop.
>
> Reboot and fans and overclocks will load up with no hassle.