# How do I overclock my gtx 1080 on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: nvidia, gpu

I installed the latest Nvidia drivers (version 375.66). I can access the configuration tool by entering

```
nvidia-settings
```

in the terminal.

This guide says to set the value of coolbits to 12 to configure clock and fan speed and then do a reboot. 
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA/Tips_and_tricks

The problem is my xorg.conf file is reset after rebooting.

I used

```
sudo chattr +i /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

to stop it from being rewritten but this happened

image.ibb.co/cr5vLF/pic_1.png

image.ibb.co/dBdX0F/pic_2.png

image.ibb.co/bYeuEa/pic_3.png

image.ibb.co/hTfqnv/pic_4.png

So I used

```
sudo chattr -i /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

to undo my change

What am I doing wrong?

btw, this post wasn't helpful

[Nvidia 1070 Overclocking Help Needed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/859218/nvidia-1070-overclocking-help-needed)

Comment: *btw, this post wasn't helpful* Yeah, an unanswered question. What's the point of mentioning it?

Comment: maybe this helps
https://gist.github.com/bsodmike/369f8a202c5a5c97cfbd481264d549e9